# Shiny Server not working when including shinyalert package - works fine in rStudio

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyalert

When attempting to run this simple app on the local shiny-server I get "Disconnected from the Server" with the console showing "The application unexpectedly exited."

The app works fine if I remove the references to "shinyalert".

The app works fine in rStudio - R Version 4.1.2.

This is the first time that I am using "shinyalert".

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)

ui <- fluidPage(
  "Hello, world!"
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  shinyalert(text = "Hi")
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Try updating the packages, all works for me. Also have a look at the log file for the `shiny-server`

Comment: Thanks for having a look.  For some reason this error doesn't produce a log file in /var/log/shiny-server/?  Do you know how I would check if the packages are up to date for shiny server?  It works fine for me in rStudio...